# Neighbour left ladder tied to roof

Tags: roofing

My neighbour did some roof work 4 months ago and has left a ladder section on the roof, it's tied at the top round chimney stack and the bottom of ladder is tied around guttering. We are exposed to strong winds and I'm worried that the ladder could come loose and fall. Any advice would be welcome. I've mentioned my concerns to him but he seems to think there's no problem.

Comment: doesn't he want his ladder back?!

Comment: Are you and your neighbor living under a common roof?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic, because it's about possible legal advice not do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you live, you can complain to your town which may have ordinances against this. It could be considered construction debris or a building safety hazard. Your local code enforcement department should be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If it does damage your property, you can of course take him to court...

Comment: Perfectly reasonable answer. +1.